# Find Java Error

Tags: java

Is there any error in the following Java code? I did not find one when I ran it.

```
public class WayToGo 
{

    private int aa, bb;

    public void WayToGo(int a, int b) 
    {
        aa = a;
        bb = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you having problems? then why do you ask?

Comment: It's not at all clear what the question is here - please clarify what it is that you are asking

Comment: Did you compile it? Did you get any errors? Your machine is a better compiler than any human...

Comment: public void WayToGo(int a, int b) it is declared as a method? if yes change it to public void wayToGo(int a, int b) and if it is a constructor and i think it is the case use public WayToGo(int a, int b)

Answer (score 5):

If this is supposed to be a constructor :

```
public void WayToGo( int a,int b)
```

change it to :

```
public WayToGo( int a,int b)
```

A constructor has no return type. Not even void.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WayToGo {

  private int aa, bb;

  public WayToGo(int a, int b) {
    ***this.aa*** = a;
    ***this.bb*** = b;
  }
}
```